# How to integrate codeigniter website from live to local server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website source code which is built in codeigniter. I am trying to setup it into local wamp server but not working properly.

I have done following things:

1. Create a database UTF-8 with database name "fc2" and import live server database.
2. Configure aplications/config/config.php by setting base_url.
3. Configure aplications/config/database.php by set databse host,username,password and database name.

But its not working. (Screen Shot attached).

[image]

.htaccess file looks like this

[image]

Please help me for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about the htaccess file ??

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: what error occurred, is it display anything on page ?

Comment: is short_open tag in php.ini is ON or OFF? set it to ON 
I see the image with the php code in page title

Comment: @Renish A R: No it shows nothing on the page. Shows blank page but in browser tab title it shows PHP code. you can see that in attached image.

Comment: Have you tried setting your log threshold to 4 (all messages displayed) on your config file? It should be the following line: $config['log_threshold'] = 0; and checked through the log file? defaults on application/log directory unless otherwise set on the same config.

Answer (score 0):

try in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sys.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

assumming that **index.php** is your index page.

and **sys** is your system folder and **app** is your application folder.

and change in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem I think is with the htaccess. Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /FOLDER_NAME/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

change FOLDER_NAME with the name of the local directory.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have put the base url in the config.php file with "http://".If not put "http://" and check

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder_name/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check if php installed properly in the stack.

Maybe reinstalling the WAMP stack might help.

Alternately I would be curious to check maybe in XAMPP to see if its something with the wamp.